# How to properly set up admob in Android to tell the difference between ad revenue

Tags: android, xml, admob

I would like to determine which portion of the revenue generated by my application is in the form of interstitial ads vs a normal adview.

I have the following two lines of code in my manifest file, where x is my publisher ID (they are the exact same):

```
 <meta-data android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
 <meta-data android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_PUBLISHER_ID" />
```

First of all, did I set this up properly via the manifest file to generate the data I want, or do I need to do something different?

Second, how do I find out which ad type is doing better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems to indicate that you need to set up a separate pubid so they can be treated distinctly...

> The richer, more heavyweight nature of InterstitialAd is reflected by
>   its definition not as a View but rather an Object requiring more
>   distinct instantiation, load and display steps.
>
> Usage is nevertheless very similar to AdView:
>
> ```
> Import com.google.ads.*
> Declare the instance
> Create it, specifying an AdMob Publisher ID distinct from any used for banners
> ```

http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/advanced.html